# custom get_category_link() wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello everybody!

I need some help with a function in wordpress, the function is get_category_link(), i'm trying to custom this function or create anoter to send the parent category child to another page instead of archive.php.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right this part of codex should answer your question [Wordpress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

The main idea is that you can create custom templates for categories and override default archive.php